# Wall command not found Debian

Tags: linux, bash, debian

The wall command does not seem to be on my Debian distro. Already updated packages and upgraded but still no wall command.

Whenever I do wall the output is

```
-bash: wall: command not found
```

Comment: It seems like a path problem. See if this link helps http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/newbie/173800-wall-command-not-found.html

Comment: @StephanyDionysio That was one of the first solutions I found, however, the distro of Debian I was running didn't have bdsutils. See ThomasDickey's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is part of the `bsdutils` package:

```
sudo apt-get install bsdutils
dpkg -L bsdutils
```

On my Debian7, for instance the listing shows

```
/.
/bin
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/logger
/usr/bin/renice
/usr/bin/script
/usr/bin/scriptreplay
/usr/bin/wall
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man8
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/logger.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/renice.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/script.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/scriptreplay.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/wall.1.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/bsdutils
/usr/share/doc/bsdutils/README.script
/usr/share/doc/bsdutils/copyright
/usr/share/doc/bsdutils/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/bsdutils/changelog.gz
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/bsdutils
```

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much. Been trying everything